# Vue Element-UI Nav-Menu color doesnt change after using default theme

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-component

I was trying to change nav-menu color and applying default-theme to change its color. i followed the step as [documentation said](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/custom-theme) , but my nav color didn't change

here is my code in main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import ElementUI from 'element-ui'
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-default/index.css'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router-config.js'
import 'vue-awesome/icons'
import Icon from 'vue-awesome/components/Icon.vue'
Vue.component('icon', Icon)
Vue.use(ElementUI)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

What did i do wrong?